# react/webpack not deploying correctly to gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, webpack, github-pages

I have a react/webpack app that I'm trying to move from a digital ocean server to github pages, but am having some difficulty. The site ran fine on digital ocean and locally, but for some reason deploying to gh-pages, the site doesn't work, the title is off, etc.

I assume it's because whatever my `dist` directory is serving, as in the `index.html` file and bundles aren't configured, but I'm not sure what the issue is.

I want my `index.html` in `dist` to mirror what my `index.html` in `public` is doing since that was working fine:

`dist/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Webpack App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <script defer="defer" src="495.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

`public/index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="Dumbnail" content="Create. Clown. Enjoy." />
    <!-- add good meta description -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <title>Dumbnail</title>
    <!-- The Ultimate Memeshot Maker -->
    <!-- Start Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages
      // MIT License
      // https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages
      // This script checks to see if a redirect is present in the query string,
      // converts it back into the correct url and adds it to the
      // browser's history using window.history.replaceState(...),
      // which won't cause the browser to attempt to load the new url.
      // When the single page app is loaded further down in this file,
      // the correct url will be waiting in the browser's history for
      // the single page app to route accordingly.
      (function (l) {
        if (l.search[1] === "/") {
          var decoded = l.search
            .slice(1)
            .split("&")
            .map(function (s) {
              return s.replace(/~and~/g, "&");
            })
            .join("?");
          window.history.replaceState(
            null,
            null,
            l.pathname.slice(0, -1) + decoded + l.hash
          );
        }
      })(window.location);
    </script>
    <!-- End Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages -->
  </head>
  <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
  <script
    async
    src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-4TJB1SJH1Z"
  ></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag("js", new Date());

    gtag("config", "G-4TJB1SJH1Z");
  </script>
  <body>
    <script
      async
      src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-2806029732302260"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The background when the site is deployed on `gh-pages` is the correct background color for my app, but the screen is blank and the title is off. The title is an easy fix, but my question is what's happening to cause this, why isn't webpack serving the same file or building the correct file that's in `public`.

My `webpack.config` file:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [".", "node_modules"],
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".scss"],
    fallback: {
      util: require.resolve("util/"),
      path: false,
      assert: false,
      os: false,
      fs: false,
      browser: false,
      module: false,
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|less|css)$/,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: "file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]!extract-loader!html-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: { chunks: "all" },
  },
  stats: {
    excludeAssets: /\.map$/,
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({})],
  mode: "production",
};
```

This may be an easy fix or a hard one, couldn't find anything online that I didn't try doing and didn't help. I don't think it's an issue of my `homepage` or any other classic `gh-pages` issues, I think it's just an issue with my `dist` or build in general. I've deployed other react apps to `gh-pages` but never webpack and it's very frustrating.

I also get this error in the browser when I go to my `gh-pages` site:

```
495.js:2 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #299; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=299 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at t.createRoot (495.js:2:527587)
    at 8689 (main.js:2:103237)
    at i (main.js:2:257812)
    at main.js:2:261534
    at i.O (main.js:2:258121)
    at main.js:2:261549
    at main.js:2:261554
```

Not sure what's going on there either, but I have the import statement of react and my `.babelrc` is configured for react imports.